# Impex for Media type in Hybris

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, impex

Does anybody knows how create an impex in order to add a new row in media item in hybris without creating or using MediaContainer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean mime type? if yes, you create media like below

```
$catalog-id=testCatalog
$catalog-version=Online
$catalogversion=catalogversion(catalog(id),version)[unique=true,default=$catalog-id:$catalog-version]
INSERT_UPDATE Media ; $catalogversion[unique=true] ; code[unique=true] ; realfilename ; @media[translator=de.hybris.platform.impex.jalo.media.MediaDataTranslator]                                             ; mime[default='text/plain']
                    ;                              ; siteMapMedia      ; sitemap.vm   ; jar:de.hybris.platform.acceleratorservices.constants.AcceleratorServicesConstants&/acceleratorservices/test/sitemap.vm ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You shod try something like this:

```
 INSERT_UPDATE Media;code[unique=true];@media[translator=de.hybris.platform.impex.jalo.media.MediaDataTranslator];mime[default='image/jpeg'];$catalogVersion
                       ;imgName;$siteResource/96Wx96H/imgName.jpg;;
```